# I18n: how can I guard against empty interpolation arguments?

Tags: ruby, internationalization

Given the following i18n key:

```
greeting: "Hi %{name}! Feeling %{adjective}?"
```

If I call `I18n.t!("greeting", adjective: "strigine")`, I get an exception: `I18n::MissingInterpolationArgument`. This is good.

However, if I pass no arguments at all, I just get the raw string.

```
I18n.t!("greeting") # => "Hi %{name}! Feeling %{adjective}?"
```

I want to ensure that this doesn't happen. **Is there a version of this method call that raises if no arguments are given**, or do I have to code it myself?

Answer (score 3):

## I18n does this on purpose

The reasons are [documented in the tests](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/v0.7.0/lib/i18n/tests/interpolation.rb#L6-L21) as follows:

> If no interpolation parameter is not given, I18n should not alter the
>   string. This behavior is due to three reasons:
>
> - Checking interpolation keys in all strings hits performance, badly;
> - This allows us to retrieve untouched values through I18n. For example I could have a middleware that returns I18n lookup results in
>     JSON to be processed through Javascript. Leaving the keys untouched
>     allows the interpolation to happen at the javascript level;
> - Security concerns: if I allow users to translate a web site, they can insert %{} in messages causing the I18n lookup to fail in every
>     request.

### How to work around it

If you want an exception in this case, you can define a method like this:

```
  # Needed because I18n will happily return the raw template string if given
  # no interpolation arguments
  # https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/v0.7.0/lib/i18n/tests/interpolation.rb#L6-L21
  def i18n_strict_t!(key, options = {})
    localized = I18n.t!(key, options)
    if missing = localized.match(I18n::INTERPOLATION_PATTERN)
      fail I18n::MissingInterpolationArgument.new(
        missing.captures.first, options, localized
      )
    end
    localized
  end
```

Usage:

```
i18n_strict_t!("greeting")
# => I18n::MissingInterpolationArgument: missing
# interpolation argument "name" in
# "Hi %{name}! Feeling %{adjective}?" ({} given)
i18n_strict_t!("greeting", name: "Carla", adjective: "taciturn")
# => "Hi Carla! Feeling taciturn?"
```

Or for slower but simpler implementation:

```
def i18n_strict_t!(key, options = {})
  options[:force_interpolation] = true if options.empty?
  I18n.t!(key, options)
end
```